# How to load the appropriate image for an iPhone model using the same storyboard file?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

Is there any way to set different images with different sizes for each iPhone model to the same imageView using the same storyBoard.

I think that doing this programmatically is not the good way.

I googled it for hours and i can't find what are Apple recommendations for doing this.

I am using Autolayout for adapting my UI to iPhone screen size, but my problem is how to change images depending on the device screen size.

Any recommendations?

I set my size class in the stroyboard like this : W Compact and H Regular so it is for all iPhones in portrait.

Where do I put images for iPhone 4s 5 6 6plus in the Asset catalog?? Here a screenshot for my asset catalog:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by using Asset Catalogs. Place different image for @1x, @2x and @3x. It will automatically load the correct image. For details about asset catalog click [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/CustomizingImageSetsforSizeClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH10-SW1).

**EDITED**

You can drag drop your images according to your device.

Look this for reference:

[image]

Comment: this is for launch images, what about subviews or uiimageviews of a uiviewcontroller for example

Comment: Check the link I have given. You can use device specific from right panel and give images according to size classes

Comment: I did the problem is i didn't see where to put image for every device.
check the screenshot in my question

Comment: Why iphone 4s and iphone 6 simulators are loading the same image 2x??

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new image set in your asset catalog, you can define different images for different devices

[image]

Comment: How do i know where to put images for iphone 4 5 6 and 6 plus in my asset catalog? I edited my question you can see the screenshot in the link

Comment: You should know it. iPhone 3GS & older versions, iPad 1 & 2 use 1x images. The rest of all devices uses retina (which is 2x), except for iPhone 6 Plus which uses 3x.

Comment: @CeceXX did you see the screenshot in the link in my question?